# Random Word from Different Lists using the random module

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to do a hangman game with a few twists and I used a random module to make a random choice from a few text files with different topics like animals, food, countries.. that I transferred to different lists and I don't know how to make python choose now a random word from all the lists. What I mean is I want it to choose a random list and from the list a random word I didn't find any solutions to this on the internet yet but maybe I'm just dumb

```
import random

colors_txt = open('colors.txt', 'r')
color_lst = []
for color in colors_txt:
    color_lst.append(color.replace('\n', ''))

random_color = random.sample(color_lst, 1)
```

This is the code for example I know there is function random.choice() instead but I just used this one

Comment: So you have a list of lists and you want to choose a random item from a random list in that list?

Comment: No I have 4 lists with just a lot of words and I want to choose a random word from a random list out of that 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking

```
import random

lists = [[...], [...], ...]

chosenList = random.choice(lists)
output = random.choice(chosenList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import random

lists = [...] #your lists as a list of lists
#picks a list randomly
randomList = random.choice(lists)
#picks an item in the randomly found list
result = random.choice(randomList)
```